# SimpleSchema update error

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm trying to create a favorite button by saving the usersId to the logged in users account. The concept is, if there is a userId (user is a favorite), else user is not a favorite. The problem is I'm getting an error `update failed: Error: Favorites must be an array` and I'm not sure what this means.

Path: `schema.js`

```
Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    "favorites.$.favorite": {
        type: Object
    }
});
```

Path: `studentlist.js`

```
Template.student.events({
'click .favourite':function(event,template) {
      console.log('click');
        var candidateId = this._id;

        Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId() }, { $set: { "profile.favorites": candidateId }});
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: No problem Andreas, I'll take that on board. Still learning the right way to do things.

Comment: Have you attached the schema to the collection with `aldeed:collection2`? Why are you trying to set `favorites` to an ID, which generally is a String, when you specified that it should be an array with `favorites.$`? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two errors.

as of the error, you must have defined `Favorites` property to be an array. and in the code you're trying to update with `$set` command.

when you're inserting an item into an array in MongoDB, you've to use `$push` operator.

and the second problem you'll face after fixing this one would be the improper data type insertion. because you've defined `favorite` to be an object, but trying to insert a mere id.